# How to call `next()` during for await iteration

Tags: javascript, typescript, generator

Suppose I have the following functions:

```js
async function *innerGen(){
  let i = 0;
  while (true){
    i = (yield i); // receive the next value from the caller
  }
}

async function *gen(){
  for await (const value of innerGen()){
    // how to pass the next value to the innerGen
  }
}
```

How can I pass values from `gen` to the `yield i` in `innerGen` using for await syntax?

I have googled keywords like `for await`, `next()`, `yield` etc. The only way I found to pass value to the `innerGen`'s yield is calling `next(value)` manually. But normally we call generators using `for await` without manually calling `next()`, is there a solution?

Comment: the only way to pass the value as you require is to use `.next(value)` as you have found, as this is how (async) generator functions work

Comment: The short version is you can't with this syntax.